# Issue By Lastlocation

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I write a program that determine my Location. I follow only the instructions from Google pages [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#permissions) and [this](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html#Starting).
When the program runs on my Galaxy note 4 (android 5.0.1), it gives me a popup to choose my account then I choose that but after that comes other empty popup and stays there, without to give me my location.
But when I click outside the popup, the popup goes and I see the map normally without my location.

I have only one class, this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;
    private static final String DIALOG_ERROR = "dialog_error";
    private boolean mResolvingError= false;
    private static final String STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR = "resolving_error";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();   

        mResolvingError = savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR,false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(!mResolvingError)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    };

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if(mResolvingError)
            return;
        else if(result.hasResolution()){
                 try {
                         mResolvingError = true;
                         result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
                     } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                         mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                     }
             }
             else{
                 showErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode());
                 mResolvingError = true;
             }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(mLastLocation != null){
            //mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            //mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
        ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR,errorCode);
        dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"errordialog");
    }

    public void onDialogDismissed(){
        mResolvingError =false;
    }

    /* A fragment to display an error dialog */
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

        public ErrorDialogFragment(){};

        public Dialog onCreatDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
            return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this.getActivity(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
            mResolvingError = false;

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                        !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, mResolvingError);
    }
}
```

and my manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.secondmapapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAOybgKFHhY0M3Mv_b0RbjT6yrIQCMWDHs"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this section is wrong

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

and must be changed into

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

The problem is where you specifies the API Type.

Comment: No, and no popup appears more.

Comment: this is from console, there is no problem

Comment: they are the last two lines from console, in the console there is no problem.
Starting activity com.example.secondmapapp.MainActivity on device 80cdd82e
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.secondmapapp/.MainActivity }

Comment: should I make screenshot for my LogCat?

Comment: Can you see my method onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)?
Is this ok? Because when I run my program with debugger, I can see my longitude and latitude. But the map does not go to this place.

Comment: There might be some errors / warning regards to the location. have a deep search.

Comment: I found three warnings: 1-ResourcesManager :Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
2- ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

3-ActivityThread: ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());

Comment: OMG,What's this! Do one thing, folow this tutorial and tell me the result http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

Comment: Your tutorial displays the longitude and latitude, and my program can do that, and displays it in a toast without any problem, my problem is that my program does not go to the location, and i want that the program goes to my location on the map, and not only displays that as a number.

Comment: How about this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/?

Comment: thaaaanks, I found the answer in the tutorials.

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :)